# yii2 image path giving 404 error in img tag

Tags: php, yii2

Image is not accessible in img tag. 
View code is as follows:-

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/web/uploads/'.$model->logo, ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing']);?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

made some changes in .htaccess file, and the problem is solved.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# deal with admin first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/(admin)
RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/uploads/(.*)$ backend/web/uploads/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/advanced/backend/web/(assets|css|uploads)/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/(admin) 
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/advanced/(assets|css) 
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/advanced/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|uploads)/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove **/web**

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web').'/uploads/'.$model->logo, ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing']);?>
```

Comment: where you upload your file  ??

Comment: and how to access your backend from server, with yii serve or http://localhost/project/backend/web

Comment: show the 404 image link , and check is this image exist  in your folder or not .

Comment: where is your backend folder in url ??

Comment: http://localhost/advanced/admin/uploads/158197891d9444.jpg giving 404 but file:///D:/xampp/htdocs/advanced/backend/web/uploads/IMG00015-20130524-085558190af0611a6.jpg is accessible.

Comment: there is htccess rule defined for backend. ie. admin is used instead of backend

Answer (score 0):

could be the relative path

```
<?= Html::img(Yii::getAlias('@web'). '.'. 
       DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'uploads' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$model->logo, 
        ['alt'=>'some', 'class'=>'thing']);?>
```